# Adding a title to gvisGeoChart

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

I am having trouble adding a title to gvisGeoChart in the googlevis package.

Here is the code I am using:

```
test <- gvisGeoChart(state.data[["MA"]], locationvar = 'Location', colorvar = 'RateofLVP',
                 options=list(region="US-MA", 
                              displayMode="markers", 
                              resolution="provinces",
                              width=600, height=400,
                              title='TESTING MAPS',
                              colorAxis="{values:[1, 5],
                              colors:[\'yellow',\'red']}"))
```

When I run this code, it produces the correct geochart, but there is no title at the top of the chart.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: looks like you haven't properly closed `colorAxis="{values:[1, 5],`

Comment: thanks for the help! sorry i miss typed the code.  I retyped it to adress your concern.

Comment: I increased the chart width and height to 1000 and it did not make a difference.

Comment: just noticed `title` is not included in the [configuration-options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options) for a GeoChart -- may not be available...?

Comment: ah i see damn.  do you know of any way to add in the title to the page at all?

Comment: not sure how `r` works -- but in HTML, just add a `<div>` above it -- there is usually a `<div>` for the chart -- see example ^ -- something like --> `<div>Title</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a possible solution, I can replace the text in the header part of the googleVis chart with the code for a title in the html format.  Thanks for the help!